# jquery in the middle of html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu that is included by php in all my pages. to avoid adding `<script` to each of this pages I decided to place the script tag right after this menu close div, so php include the menu and its script.

I don't want this script to stops parsing the other HTML on my page, I know the best practise is to place it before the closing body tag.

**The question here is, is it blocking my page? or it will only block if I put it on head or use the `$(document).ready(function() {` ?**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...html
        <div id="menu">itens</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        ...html
    </body>
</html>
```

the script.js

```
$("#menu").click(function() {
 $("#message").show();
 $("#back").show();
});
```

Comment: It will not block your page dont worry about that, In websites there are script which is loaded at the middle of large HTML page.

Comment: I think there is not any problem with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to load this script after full page loadup you can use **defer** keyword.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>
```

defer will start loading this js file after execution of html and other js files.

Comment: oh, it is amazing! even in localhost I notice it is now faster to load! thank you.

Comment: Wc, There is another keyword called 'async', if you want to load your scripts asynchronously.